# Android sound latency using SoundPool

Tags: android, audio, latency

```
public class AndroidSound implements Sound {
int soundId;
SoundPool soundPool;

public AndroidSound(SoundPool soundPool, int soundId) {
    this.soundId = soundId;
    this.soundPool = soundPool;
}

@Override
public void play(float volume) {
    soundPool.play(soundId, volume, volume, 0, 0, 1);
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    soundPool.unload(soundId);
}}





public class Assets{

public Music theme;
public static Sound sound;

public static void load(Game game) {
        theme = game.getAudio().createMusic("theme.mp3");
        theme.setLooping(true);
        theme.setVolume(0.85f);
        theme.play();

        sound = game.getAudio().createSound("death.wav");
    }
}
```

Then I play this sound in different class by calling play() on it, but it plays with really huge delay, something around 500ms. Why is that? I tried looking for solution, but there is tons of people with that problem and I haven't found any answer that actually worked. Most of topics was bit old tho, maybe there is a simple solution for this already, counting on your help.

```html
public class AndroidAudio implements Audio {
    AssetManager assets;
    SoundPool soundPool;

    public AndroidAudio(Activity activity) {
        activity.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        this.assets = activity.getAssets();
        this.soundPool = new SoundPool(20, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public Sound createSound(String filename) {
        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor assetDescriptor = assets.openFd(filename);
            int soundId = soundPool.load(assetDescriptor, 0);
            return new AndroidSound(soundPool, soundId);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load sound '" + filename + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you creating `AndroidSound` object instance?

Comment: Why is it playing with delay? I'm so frustrated with this already, can't find any good solutions. Should I use something other than SoundPool? Or is there any possibility it's my devices fault? (I have no option to check on any other)

Comment: so you call `play` inside `onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status)` method and after you call `play` you notice half second delay?

Comment: i call play inside completely different class, this load(Game game) method is called in my loading screen when i start the app, so sound is assigned long before i call play on it (like this Assets.sound.play(0.85f)). No onLoadComplete method, just in my method that detects when character dies (thus "death.wav").

Comment: I started noticing a 500ml delay in all sounds from my game app. After spending an afternoon trying different things, I accidentally discovered it was my new Galaxy Buds Pro earbuds causing a half second delay for everything from the app. Irritating for a $160 device. I work on my game in a noisy Starbucks. Switching to 'Gaming Mode' in Wearable settings didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will be helpful now but also answering.

**Use of SoundPool**

1)First load your audio as required in the levels in the beginning of application initialization.Suppose you need 5 sound in the level load them in the beginning and keep the soundID's handy.

2) Now on any event just call play with the soundID.

3) This plays with a very less delay while I debugged from SoundPool play till HAL layer.Around 10-15 ms in my device.

*For more info on SoundPool implementation follow my github thread:*
https://github.com/sauravpradhan/Basic-Audio-Routing